# Echoing a mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been attempting to echo a mysqli query that selects all the data in the table from a specific field yet currently my code will not print anything on the screen, I also receive no indication of any error from within the console :/

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT field_name, FROM table_name");
print_r($result);
?>
```

I have already previously attempted to echo `$result` rather than `print_r` yet neither work so I'm not entirely sure what's wrong. Its my first time using phpMyAdmin :/

Comment: You have a syntax error in your sql query, i.e: the comma after `field_name`. This will cause a 500 error, hence the blank screen. Try enable error report on your PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using mysqli you should read result by `mysqli_fetch_row` or something like that.
and suggest you use mysql_pdo instead.

```php
<?php
//if error happend,this will display error on page
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT field_name FROM table_name");

//print result like this
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    print_r($row);
}
```